# Hadamard's product of Riemann's $\xi$ function

Tags: number-theory

I can prove that the order of $\xi(s)$ is at most 1. Therefore, from Hadamard's factorization theorem, it follows that
$$\xi(s)=Ae^{Bs}\prod_\rho{ \left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)e^{s/\rho}}$$
where A,B are constant, and $\rho$'s are zeros of $\xi(s)$. I also know that $A=\xi(0)=\frac{1}{2}$.

However, in Riemann's paper, 
$$\xi(s)=\xi(0)\prod_\rho \left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)$$
where $\prod$ means that $\rho$ should be paired with $1-\rho$ in order to make sure the infinite product converges.

Therefore, I am wondering how to derive Riemann's result JUST from Hadamard's factoriztion theorem mentioned above.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That's not quite what [Hadamard's factorization theorem](http://books.google.ca/books?id=MVk5jCQVuiYC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22#v=onepage&q&f=false) says.

Since the order of $\xi$ is at most one it has [genus either zero or one](http://books.google.ca/books?id=MVk5jCQVuiYC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=genus+of+entire+function&source=bl&ots=wYZVeoTjxZ&sig=Y3-yhVw3AtxoQrevTQPirXXdFv8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v0q5UKPqCqyLyAHkw4HQCw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA), and it is this genus which determines the form of the Weierstrass product.

Riemann's product shows that the genus of $\xi$ is zero.

Comment: Could you show me some relevant references?

Comment: @Y.Fan I linked you directly to the relevant pages of the reference: Boas, *Entire Functions*.