# Derive Xi Function's Infinite Product

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

The Infinite Product of the Xi Function is $\xi(s)={1\over 2}\prod_{\rho}^\ (1- {s\over \rho})$. But I don't know how to derive it, I know how to derive the Product formula for the zeta function but I am confused in this case. I saw this on Wikipedia. I know Xi Function is connected to gamma Function and Zeta Function in a very unique formula. There is also a summation of the Xi Function, but I want to know how to derive this infinite product.

Comment: I will write this as a comment, since I am not 100% sure it works that way: Entire functions with prescribed zeroes are determined up to an exponential/prefactor iirc . So if you know the zeroes of the Xi function $\xi$ and then you take the quotient of the Xi function as you know it and the product formula i.e. $\frac{\xi(s)}{\Pi (1-s/p)}$. Then this should be an entire function and then you have to quote the Hadamard or Weierstrass product theorem(?). But I am not certain, hence this is only a comment.

Comment: the gist of it is that by general Hadamard theory one can write $\xi(s)=Ce^{as}\Pi_{\rho, \Im \rho >0} {(1- {s\over \rho})(1- {s\over \bar \rho})}$ with the product part $P(s)$ absolute convergent and satisfying $P(s)=P(1-s)$; but since $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ this gives $e^{as}=e^{a-as}$ which of course implies $a=0$ and then $C=1/2$ comes from the standard evaluation $\xi(0)=1/2$

Comment: Partly addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288139).